# Transmittance of a capacitively coupled shunt resonator

Tags: rf, filter, passive-networks, passive-filter, high-pass-filter

I have been trying to understand the expression of **|s21|** for the resonator mentioned in this [article](https://journals.aps.org/prapplied/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevApplied.3.014007). For a circuit similar to the drawn below, in which R1 is used as the temperature sensitive element, the transmittance at resonance is given by $$ |S21| = 2\kappa\frac{G_0}{G_1+G_0} $$ where
$$\kappa = \frac{C_2C_3}{C_2^2 + C_3^2}$$ 
$$G_0 = 4\pi^2({C_2^2 + C_3^2})Z_0f_0^2$$ I couldn't obtain these expressions on my own. Can somebody explain me the logic behind this derivation ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2felRj0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

An author of the paper offers an explanation in his [PhD dissertation](https://aaltodoc.aalto.fi/bitstream/handle/123456789/14413/isbn9789526059204.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), page 85.

Answer (score 0):

One method is impedance ratio divider.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYWxUI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However an easier method is probably Admittance or Conductance ratios.

Comment: I've already tried this method but it doesn't simplify to the expression above.

Comment: Perhaps matrix methods will work. but beyond me.  Here's what it can look like https://goo.gl/PbzFHr  Not too common to me and R1 does nothing useful. You dont show G1, but similar I expect.

Comment: or closer values https://goo.gl/CDLFWE or even higher Q https://goo.gl/tC3fNh

Comment: Strange L, must be in the equation but isnt shown and they say neglect G1 << G0  as the dominant resonance is determined by L1C1 get Q from high ratios of C1/C2 and C1/C3 slightly shifts resonance determined by L1C1. So my conclusion is same as yours ??? It does not seem correct  . http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/213291/local_213291.pdf  for others to read